# how to use jQuery plug in content pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a master page and 3 content pages, i have used a jQuery plug in for persian calendar, when i use the plug in in master page every thing seems fine, the problem is i want to use this plug in just in ONE of my content pages, so i cant use it in master page, but the plug in wont work when used in content page.Here is my code in content page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Content.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication3.WebForm4" %>

<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="Compressed/skins/aqua/theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="Compressed/jalali.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="Compressed/calendar-setup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Compressed/lang/calendar-fa.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<input id="date_input" type="text" onclick="return date_input_onclick()" runat="server" /><input id="date_btn" type="button" runat="server"/>

 <script type="text/javascript" >
    Calendar.setup({
        inputField: 'date_input',
        button: 'date_btn',
        ifFormat: '%Y/%m/%d',
        dateType: 'jalali'
    });
  </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
```

could anyone help me?

Comment: Are all of your `script` tags in the correct order?

Comment: yes, when i use it in master page in works fine

Comment: share your master file's source